# Fluent NHibernate parameterized typedef mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Does anyone know how the following HBM property mapping could be translated to Fluent?

```
<typedef class="uNHAddIns.UserTypes.EncryptedString, uNHAddIns" name="Encrypted">
  <param name="encryptor">uNhAddIns.UserTypes.uNHAddinsEncryptor, uNhAddIns</param>
  <param name="encryptionKey">myRGBKey</param>
</typedef>
```

It doesn't have to work specifically for the EncryptedString type, but I need to know if it's possible to add params to CustomType mappings in Fluent.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is not supported by Fluent NHibernate at this time.  Here is a link to the issue in GitHub:

https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/issues/193